# Firefox border messed up after transform

Tags: css, firefox, border

This happens on firefox, where I have a border on an element and if I transform the element, the border becomes all messed up.  It is more noticeable on monitor screens.

```
<div>
  Hello World
</div>

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: scale(0.625, 0.625) translate(50px, 50px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tcspd7za/1/

Answer (score 1):

A dirty work around might fix your issue. Try add this:  `-moz-transform: scale(.9999);`

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: scale(0.625, 0.625) translate(50px, 50px);
  -moz-transform: scale(.9999);
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need it to scale which in this case it doesnt